# Deleting questions with answers and no upvotes?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I recently answered a question:

[Matrix Algebra Question (Linear Algebra)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508896/matrix-algebra-question-linear-algebra)

The author, now that they have an answer, immediately deleted the question.

Is this the way the site was intended to work?

What stops anyone from deleting questions as soon as they get an answer?

Comment: Some older posts, which seem related: [Why do some users delete their questions after receiving an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8528/why-do-some-users-delete-their-questions-after-receiving-an-answer), [People who ask homework questions and then remove them](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4277/people-who-ask-homework-questions-and-then-remove-them)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thanks. This seems like a weakness in the system as a person can just wait for an answer and not give anyone time to upvote. Those responses also seem to validate my suspicion that it is some form of cheating. Of course, I also spent all the time writing an answer and am disappointed that this seems like it is by design of the system. Regards

Comment: I voted to undelete. You may want to flag the question for moderator attention as well.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Thank you for the vote of confidence! Regards

Comment: You could vote to undelete as well and then there is only one more person needed, even before moderators show up.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: I did not know that. Thank you!

Comment: (Undeleted now.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: that was quick! Thank you for the support! Regards

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Perhaps there should be a meta thread "Questions to undelete because they have good answers" so as to systematically address the problem which was brought up and then solved in this particular case.

Comment: I used to mention request to undelete in chat. We used to have [specific chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6657259#6657259) for stuff about closing, reopening, undeleting etc. However, this chatroom is much less active now, so main chatroom might be better. Anyway, using a meta thread, reopen requests would have much better visibility.